# JQ: A list with multiple values for one key

Tags: jq

Using jq, I want to get a list of application names, all versions and server name. The list should not contain information about the latest version.

Input:

```json
{
  "software": {
    "app_1": {
      "0.0.1": {
        "properties_1": {
          "lang": "en"
        },
        "server": "vm123-4.domain.com"
      },
      "0.0.2": {
        "properties_2": {
          "arch": "x86"
        },
        "server": "vm123-5.comain.com"
      },
      "latest_version": "0.0.2"
    },
    "app_2": {
      "1.0.1": {
        "properties_2": {
          "arch": "x86"
        },
        "server": "vm333-1.domain.com"
      },
      "latest_version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "app_33": {
      "0.44.1": {
        "properties_1": {
          "lang": "en"
        },
        "properties_2": {
          "arch": "x86"
        },
        "properties_3": {
          "boot": "true"
        },
        "server": "vm888-9.domain.com"
      },
      "1.2.2": {
        "properties_3": {
          "boot": "yes"
        },
        "server": "vm123-4.domain.com"
      },
      "latest_version": "1.2.2"
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
"app_1,  0.0.1,  vm123-4.domain.com"
"app_1,  0.0.2,  vm123-5.comain.com"
"app_2,  1.0.1,  vm333-1.comain.com"
"app_33, 0.44.1, vm888-9.comain.com"
"app_33, 1.2.2,  vm123-4.comain.com"
```

My request will only list one version of the app, but not all. I do not know how to do this.

```
.software | to_entries[] | [(.key), (.value | to_entries[] | select(.key | IN("latest_version") | not))] | "\(.[0]) \(.[1].key) \(.[1].value.server)"
```

My output:

```
"app_1  0.0.1  vm123-4.domain.com"
"app_2  1.0.1  vm333-1.domain.com"
"app_33 0.44.1 vm888-9.domain.com"
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you get the first `Output`, and what the desired result set is ?

Comment: First output is desired, the last one I got .

Comment: But your question states "The list should not contain information about the latest version.". So why is app1 0.0.2 included and app2 1.0.1 ?

Comment: The list should not contain the "latest_version" key. This key is at the same level as app_1 0.0.2, app_2 1.0.1 etc. The list should only contain "Request Output" data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.software | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value | to_entries[] | select(.key != "latest_version") | "\(.key) \(.value.server)")"
```

Will produce

```json
"app_1 0.0.1 vm123-4.domain.com"
"app_1 0.0.2 vm123-5.comain.com"
"app_2 1.0.1 vm333-1.domain.com"
"app_33 0.44.1 vm888-9.domain.com"
"app_33 1.2.2 vm123-4.domain.com"
```

As you can test [in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NqCw2PKvgD).

---

Using `--raw-output` with tabs `\t`, we can create a column like output:

```
app_1   0.0.1   vm123-4.domain.com
app_1   0.0.2   vm123-5.comain.com
app_2   1.0.1   vm333-1.domain.com
app_33  0.44.1  vm888-9.domain.com
app_33  1.2.2   vm123-4.domain.com
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xSNZBSmjKM)

Comment: Thanks @Ostone0 for the solution. It works very well !

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '.software | to_entries[] | .key as $app | .value | to_entries[] | select((.value | objects)) |  [$app, .key, .value.server] | @csv'
```

Comment: Thanks @Botje for the solution. I changed: 
```[$app, .key, .value.server] | @csv```
on
```"\($app), \(.key), \(.value.server)"```

Comment: @Ege: or replace `@csv` with `@tsv`